# Ionic 4/Cordova App - Intercept first install

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

Has anyone tried to implement some sort of event listener in Ionic 4 app to intercept incoming data from android/ios store during first installation?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to intercept? You can use Capacitor Storage to set a boolean at the first launch of your app, which will tell you if this is the first launch or not.

Comment: Hi Roshan. Please show the code you have tried. Use a "Markdown code fence" to format your code. Find "Instead of using indentation, you can also create code blocks by using “code fences”, consisting of three or more backticks or tildes:" on this help page. stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @Poney, Thanks you for your reply. Basically the scenario is: I am trying to implement Adform so when user clicks on an add banner somewhere in a website they are redirect to google play or apple store and I am trying to implemented an event listener which will track incoming params that is sent by Adform(external company) during first install of an app. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: @Loveandpeace-JoeCodeswell Thanks so much for replying, I do not have any written code because this is the first time I've encountered this sort of implementation. I've been looking over Cordova and Ionic documentations but so far I am a little blank.